# Why are these two variables synced together

Tags: python, variables

I wrote the following code:

```
grid = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]

grid2 = [[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]

grid2 = grid

grid2[0][0] = 5

print(grid2)
print(grid)
```

And this is the output:

```
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Why does the variable `grid` also get `5` in its output? These are two separate variables and I'm only changing one? Is there anyway to not have them synced?

Comment: Sounds like you could use [a quick guide to the semantics of Python variables and assignment](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: They stop being separate "variables" when you bind the same object to both.

Comment: Grid2 is a *reference* to the other Grid